# Create a new name if two folder name matches using bat

Tags: batch-file

Suppose `New Folder` is in my current directory path.

The bat file is trying to create another `New Folder` in the same path.

How to rename the second folder as `New Folder1` automatically while creating?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if exist`

```
if exist %foldername% set foldername=%foldername%1
```

this can be made more robust with a simple loop.

Although, if you have multiple folders with the same name it will end up looking like `'New Folder', 'New Folder1', 'New Folder11'`. Easy enough to get around with a separate variable for the number.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step file. Adapt as needed.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    rem How to search and name new folders  
    set "baseName=New Folder"

    rem Search the folder with baseName and greater number.
    rem Dir is generated in descending order, so the first folder is the greatest.
    set "lastFolder="
    for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /ad /o-n /b "%cd%\%baseName%*." 2^>nul ^| findstr /b /e /r /c:"%baseName%[0-9]*"') do (
        set "lastFolder=%%~nd"
        goto endSearch
    )
:endSearch

    rem Test if we found a folder
    if defined lastFolder (

        rem Folder found, get its number by eliminating the baseName part of the name
        set "lastFolderNumber=!lastFolder:%baseName%=!"

        if not defined lastFolderNumber (
            rem if it has no number, next folder should be 1
            set "lastFolderNumber=1"
        ) else (
            rem number found, add 1
            set /a lastFolderNumber+=1
        )

    ) else (
        rem No folder exist. This is the first. So no numeration
        set "lastFolderNumber="
    )

    rem create the folder
    echo Creating: "%cd%\%baseName%%lastFolderNumber%"
    mkdir "%cd%\%baseName%%lastFolderNumber%"

:endProcess
    rem clean vars
    endlocal
```